# Android + SQLite + Query

Tags: android, mysql

I've got two tables

Workout Table

Workout_ID  ---------  Workout Name

 1 ---------------------------           Chest

 2 ----------------------------           Back

Date of Workouts Table

Date_ID-------  Date of Workout------   Workout_ID

 1-----------------------22/12/13----------------  1

 2----------------------   23/12/13----------------    2

Within android, using MySqlite currently:

  i have these exact tables.

However when i come to OUTPUT my 'Date of Workouts Table' onto the screen, what MySQLite Code will i need to do so? General points would be really appreciated.

Somehow i need to take the 'Workout_ID' and compare it to the 'Workout_ID' in the Workout Table and generate 'Chest' and then output that

*EDIT* Here i've got my code which Outputs whe Workout_ID which is present in the Date of Workouts Table

```
public String getWorkoutNameInfo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_DATE_OF_WORKOUT,
            KEY_WORKOUT_NAME, KEY_DATE };           
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_DATE_WORKOUT, columns, null, null,           
            null, null, null, null);                    
    String workoutName2 = "";               
    int iWorkoutID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORKOUT_NAME);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        workoutName2 = workoutName2 + c.getString(iWorkoutID);  

            }
            System.out.println(workoutName2);

        return workoutName2;


}
```

HERE I'm trying to query my WorkoutTable WHERE my workout_id is equal to the workoutSlectedNameInfo

So i'm trying to go down the list of Workout_ID in my 'Date of Workouts Table' and compare the 1 and 2 to the Workout Table - This doesn't work - Will this Join statement allow me to do this?

public String test(String workoutSelectedNameInfo) {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Weight = "";
    open();
    ourDatabase = ourhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = ourDatabase
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT workout_name FROM WorkoutTable WHERE workout_id = ?",
                    new String[] { workoutSelectedNameInfo });

    int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORKOUT_NAME);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        Weight = Weight + c.getString(iWeight) + "\n";
    }
    c.close();
    ourDatabase.close();
    return Weight;





    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: Google for "SQL joins".  `SELECT * FROM Workouts LEFT JOIN Workout ON Workouts.Wourkout_ID = Workout.Workout_ID`

Comment: so what do you want? joining these both tables to gether?

Answer (score 0):

```
here db proper innitialised instance  
String sql = "select workoutname from WorkoutTable as wt,WorkoutDayTable wdt where wt.Workout_ID  = wdt.Workout_ID "; 
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
SELECT * FROM Workout LEFT JOIN DateofWorkout ON (Workout.Workkout_ID = DateofWorkout.Workout_ID) WHERE Workout.Workout_ID = "??????" -- use your ID to find the data

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are three basic JOINS

1. The CROSS JOIN
2. The INNER JOIN
3. The OUTER JOIN

**Plus read this simple guide you really need**, anyhow just read the [GUIDE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm), after reading you won't ask question regarding queries anymore

[Tutorial About SQLite and Android](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/)
**Edited**

```
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Workout LEFT JOIN DateofWorkout ON Workout.Workkout_ID = DateofWorkout.Workout_ID", null);


    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
```

Comment: Is it suppose to be SELECT * FROM WorkoutsTable LEFT JOIN DateofWorkout? Otherwise aren't you joining two of the same table? And thank you for the link, reading through now!

Comment: the tables above you mentioned is workout and workouts. so i thought workout means main table workouts means daily workout entries. answer is updated. check again

Comment: I've implemented the code you suggested, but i'm just receiving 'null' ?

Comment: and in this `ON (Workout.Workkout_ID = DateofWorkout.Workout_ID)` workout id should be same in both tables otherwise it wont pullout the data

Comment: at the moment mine is 'WorkoutTable.workout_id = DateofWorkout.name_of_workout' do i need to re name the column 'name_of_workout' to 'workout_id'?

Comment: actually what do you want just filter it by particular workout id or just listout all entries in the table.. if it is just listout dont use where clause...

Comment: For instance: DateofWorkout.name_of_workout in the table is "ABS Core" and Workout.Workkout_ID = 001 won't work because its not same? one is number another is a kinda name?

Comment: In my WorkoutTable i've got '1 = chest , 2 = back' and in my DateofWorkout i've got just the numbers 1 and 2. But i'm trying to look up the numbers 1 and 2 in the WorkoutTable to output the String name, like Chest

Comment: what does this mean in simple terms? ''WorkoutTable.workout_id = DateofWorkout.name_of_workout'?

Comment: meaning if workout_id and DateofWorkout.name_of_workout are equeal in both table list all of them, those mismatched entries won't show up

Comment: What if they aren't equal and are in a different order, 1 = chest and 2 = back but in the DateofWorkout it goes 2 then 1?

Comment: order is not a problem.. if you have 1 in the 1st table and 2nd table has same 1, it will show, post is edited i suggested some easy way to do that. checkout

Comment: getwritabledatabase? shouldn't it be readable since i'm trying to read data?

Comment: that was a mistake* and check there is a simple tutorial I've attached

Comment: Any ideas why it would only output one equivalent? Say i'm looking for all those with ID=1, it will only print 'Chest' once instead of for all the ones that have ID = 1

Comment: maybe the data in other table is not matching with 1

Comment: could you have a look at this please ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828120/performing-a-lookup-on-sqlite