# Performing a Lookup on SQLite

Tags: android, mysql

http://postimg.org/image/4vozphdk7/

So these are my tables;

I save my data in such a way that the Workout_ID (second figure) references the Workout_ID in the top figure.

What i need - How can i 'Look up' what Workout_ID 2 is and output the string, when it comes to displaying my table?

Done in SQLite, is this possible?

Coded Table column Names:

```
date_id = date_of_workout_id
date = date_of_workout
workout_name = workout_name
date_of_workout = DateofWorkout
workout_table = WorkoutTable
workout_id(date's one) = name_of_workout
workout_id(WorkoutTables's one) = workout_id
```

public String test(String WorkoutSelectedNameInfo) {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Weight = "";
    open();
    ourDatabase = ourhelper.getReadableDatabase();



    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT date_of_workout_id, 
   date_of_workout, workout_name FROM DateofWorkout JOIN WorkoutTable ON 
 DateofWorkout.name_of_workout = WorkoutTable.workout_id", null);
    int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORKOUT_NAME);
             while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            Weight = Weight + c.getString(iWeight) + "\n";
        }


    c.close();
    ourDatabase.close();

    System.out.println(Weight);

    return Weight;



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite, Tables, Joining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826500/sqlite-tables-joining)

Comment: `workout_id(date's one) = name_of_workout` That's a terrible choice. If it's an ID call it an id. If it's the name, call it the name.

Comment: where did you get KEY_WORKOUT_NAME from, and why are you trying to put a workout name into something called "Weight"?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

Try changing

> Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT date_of_workout_id,
>   date_of_workout, workout_name FROM DateofWorkout JOIN WorkoutTable ON 
>   DateofWorkout.name_of_workout = WorkoutTable.workout_id", null);

to

> Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT date_of_workout_id,
>   date_of_workout, workout_name FROM DateofWorkout JOIN WorkoutTable ON 
>   **DateofWorkout.workout_id = WorkoutTable.workout_id**", null);

the problem maybe is because you are comparing **name_of_workout** from **workout_id**.

A simple inner join perhaps?

```
select dow.date_id, dow.date, w.name
from workout w, date_of_workout dow
where w.workout_id = dow.workout_id
```

Comment: Can you help me with the coded solution, i've updated the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple `JOIN` can do that;

```
SELECT date_id, date, workout_name
FROM date_of_workout 
JOIN workout_table 
  ON date_of_workout.workout_id = workout_table.workout_id
```

Comment: Are you able to help me with the coded solution? I've implemented your response into my code but it doesn't display anything :(

Comment: @ChrisH Does the query display the correct result if you run it from an SQLite prompt instead of your code?

Comment: I've mocked it up, the JOIN statement works according to the mock up but in practice it isnt :( could you take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889763/using-a-cursor-and-returning-data-after-joining-two-tables , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_ID, date, workout_name
FROM workouts, dates
WHERE workouts.workout_ID = dates.workout_ID
```

Comment: Can you help me with the coded solution, i've updated the question! :)

Comment: We answer your question so you update it to a completely NEW question? I can see where this is going...