# Using a Cursor and returning data after Joining two tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a table called WorkoutTable:
http://postimg.org/image/8rw5t7u0n/

I've got a table called DateofWorkout:
http://postimg.org/image/9tqjkyszv/be35531c/

Within the DateofWorkout Table i've got the column called 'workout_id_2' which references the column called 'workout_id' in my WorkoutTable.

Basically i want to produce a table which shows the DateofWorkoutTable but instead of 'workout_id_2' i want it to show the NAMES of the workouts.

According to my mock up the following SQL code does this:

SELECT date_of_workout_id, date_of_workout, workout_name 
FROM WorkoutTable INNER JOIN DateofWorkout 
ON WorkoutTable.workout_id = DateofWorkout.workout_id_2 
ORDER BY date_of_workout_id

According to my mock up both an INNER JOIN and a LEFT JOIN will work.

Furthermore I'm trying to read this out of my actual database in my android project:

```
public String test(String WorkoutSelectedNameInfo) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String EquivofWorkoutID = "";
    String dateofworkoutid = "";
    String dateofworkout = "";


    open();
    ourDatabase = ourhelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT date_of_workout_id, date_of_workout,        
 workout_name FROM WorkoutTable LEFT JOIN DateofWorkout ON WorkoutTable.workout_id = 

DateofWorkout.workout_id_2 ORDER BY date_of_workout_id", null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
do {
    EquivofWorkoutID = EquivofWorkoutID + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(STRING_WORKOUT))+ "\n" ;
    dateofworkoutid = dateofworkoutid + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_OF_WORKOUT))+ "\n" ;
    dateofworkout = dateofworkout + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE))+ "\n" ;
} while (c.moveToNext());
}    
            c.close();

        ourDatabase.close();

    System.out.println(EquivofWorkoutID);
    System.out.println("the id date of the workout is" + dateofworkoutid );
    System.out.println("the date of the workout is" + dateofworkout );

    return EquivofWorkoutID;
}
```

As you can see i set up my code to output the values of EquivofWorkoutID, dateofworkoutid and dateofworkout. However, on execution the 'EquivofWorkoutID' actually just displays whatever is present in the WorkoutTable's STRING_WORKOUT column instead of the JOINED table. Furthermore the dateofworkoutid and dateofworkout remain as 'null' suggesting that the cursor hasn't implemented the INNER JOIN statement. How do i read out the information shown using the SQL query shown in the image? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you give your db schema and what STRING_WORKOUT, KEY_DATE_OF_WORKOUT and KEY_DATE are?

Comment: What is schema? STRING_WORKOUT = workout_name , KEY_DATE_OF_WORKOUT = date_of_workout_id , KEY_DATE = date_of_workout_id , they're the same thing, sorry i forgot to mention that!

Comment: by schema i meant how your tables are related and what columns are. also you're using LEFT JOIN on your code while referencing to INNER JOIN in explanation of the problem...confusing

Comment: Yeah the mock up shows that both INNER and LEFT JOIN produce the same results, i'll edit my question to make it clearer :)

Comment: I've made some edits, is that clearer?

Comment: I would suggest you to mock around your real table on a phone, so run your app on emulator (or rooted phone if you have one handy), then open terminal and run 'adb shell' and 'sqlite3 data/data/{your package}/databases/{your database file name} that will let you execute sql directly in real db